# Error in Ruby-Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby-Cucumber. And I was trying to implement a framework around for an application. But I am unable to understand this error.

```
no such file to load -- page-object (LoadError)
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `r
equire'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `r
equire'
F:/Framework/features/support/env.rb:54:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_la
nguage.rb:122:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_la
nguage.rb:122:in `load_code_file'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_
code.rb:180:in `load_file'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_
code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_
code.rb:82:in `each'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_
code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:183:i
n `load_step_definitions'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in
 `run!'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:i
n `execute!'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (req
uired)>'
C:/Ruby192/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

It seems to be a fault on my part somewhere. If anyone can help please post your answers in helping me understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to indicate that you're missing either a file or (more likely) a project dependency called: page-object.

The first line of the error explains what the problem is:

```
no such file to load -- page-object (LoadError)
```

It can be a little confusing when you're first getting used to Ruby errors, but the fourth line seems to point towards line 54 of `Framework/features/support/env.rb`:

```
F:/Framework/features/support/env.rb:54:in `<top (required)>'
```

My guess is that you need to add the [page-object](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object) gem to either your Gemfile (if you have one) or your system-wide gems.

If you **have a file** called `F:/Framework/Gemfile`, add `gem 'page-object'` just below the line in that references cucumber. Once you've added that line and saved the file, you'll need to run `bundle install`.

If you **don't have** a Gemfile, try running `gem install page-object` and then running cucumber again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have not installed "Page-object" gem on your project, so you need to install it 1st with gem install page-object command and check same is reflected in your Gemfile.
Another way is do bundle update it will take the latest gem as per your ruby version. similar to bundle install.